# Run python script remotely from Ubuntu server to multiple Redhat servers

Tags: linux, python

I want to run the python script remotely from my Ubuntu server to multiple Redhat servers.
Can anyone help how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

## Run a python script remotely via `ssh`

Depending on what you want to achieve, it may be desirable for you to send the python script via `ssh` and `stdin`, as in [asdfg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22915340):

> `cat script.py | ssh user@server python -`

*(modified to change example names)*

Note that as per comments on that answer, the script will still accept arguments, if you need to supply those:

> `cat script.py | ssh user@server python - arg1 arg2 arg3`

## Automation

You could bundle up the server names in [an array](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) in a shell script to automate the process (using key-based logins would help automate the process too):

```
#!/bin/bash

username=user
servers=(serverone servertwo serverthree)
script=/path/to/script.py

for server in ${servers[@]}; do
    cat $script | ssh $username@$server python -
done
```

Comment: @Rohith no problem, hope it works for you- if it doesn't, post feedback either on the answer or update your question; if it does, feel free to accept this as an answer!

Comment: Hi @bertieb, I am able to run the srcipt. But I have another issue now. I am trying to download the package on server using above script. But it is not downloading as we need to enter Y manually. "Enter 'y' to download packages and continue the install". Could you please let me know how to add y in script to automatically accept ?

Comment: Never Mind.. I have removed the prompt from my python script. Now i am able to run without any issues.Once again Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Hi bertieb, I am unable to run the script fully. I have a username called venkat which is added in sudoers list. To complete the installation through script, i need to run the script using root. could you please help me how to run python script using the command "sudo ./test.py" ?

Comment: @Rohith glad you overcame that hurdle. Try `cat $script | ssh $username@$server sudo python -`

Comment: I am getting below error. "sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Comment: You could try adding `-t` switch to the ssh command. Does the remote server have `Defaults requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` ?

Comment: I have tried adding -t and -tt but no luck..still same error... I see below has been configured.

Comment: # Defaults specification

#
# Disable "ssh hostname sudo <cmd>", because it will show the password in clear.
#         You have to run "ssh -t hostname sudo <cmd>".

Defaults    requiretty

Comment: You can change the `Defaults requiretty` reasonably safely, see [this answer on U&L SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122624)